# How to print ViewController of labels?

Tags: ios, xcode, label, airprint

I am making a form for users to fill out in person. After all the fields have been filled in, it shows a summary of all your inputs at the end when you are completed.

How would I go about printing this last controller of just labels? I have seen people do it with pictures, just not something with labels or something users did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would package the information in the labels programatically & manually and create a print job using the Printing API.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html

Comment: Thank you. I have figured out how to work with this!